# How to properly install PyTorch with Anaconda on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: pytorch, anaconda, ubuntu-22.04

My OS is Ubuntu 22.04

I only install Anaconda from `Anaconda3-2022.10-Linux-x86_64.sh`
And then run `conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.7 -c pytorch -c nvidia`

Then, `import torch` gives

```
File “/home/fenaux/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/init.py”, line 191, in
_load_global_deps()

File “/home/fenaux/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/init.py”, line 153, in _load_global_deps
ctypes.CDLL(lib_path, mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)

File “/home/fenaux/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ctypes/init.py”, line 382, in init
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)

OSError: libcufft.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

when I check in `anaconda3/lib` I only find `libcufft.so.11`.
I also tried with
`conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.6 -c pytorch -c nvidia`
and the result is exactly the same.
I have no other environments nor installations of PyTorch.

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved with a PR in PyTorch see here :

https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/import-torch-fails-with-fresh-conda-installation/168167

Comment: Thanks a bunch for adding value to Stackoverflow by answering your own question! When making a short answer which is mostly pointing towards a link, it is good practice to at least describe a bit what the conclusion is the user should have by visiting that link (and how it answers the original question). The reason why is that it is very possible that this link will be stale in 5 years and then your answer is not very useful anymore. Thanks again!